# How do I get the address used to access a website in java

Tags: java, html, applet, ip-address, lighttpd

I'm sorry about the terible wording of my question but I wasn't sure how else to word it.

Anyway, I have a Java Applet that is embbeded on a webpage. That webpage is then put up in the network using the webserver lighttpd. I need to from within the Java applet (through webpage accessed from different computer on the network) get the IPv4 Address of the computer which is running the server (this is the address typed in to access page, ex. "http://192.168.1.123"). I have tried everything I have found or could think of but nothing has worked so far. PLEASE help if you can.

specs:

```
-Eclipse Helios
-Windows 7
-lightTPD for windows
-webpage is html document
```

email or comment if you need more info!

thank you all in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. An applet is always run on a client computer. That is the whole distribution model.

Comment: I know but in order to get the correct database file i need to have the ip address of the computer running the webserver. this is for something where i CANNOT have the ip-address hard-coded into the java program

Comment: *"I have tried everything I have found"*  What have you found or tried?  Why did it fail?  Most importantly, what feature are you trying to offer by achieving the stated task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about generating the page with the java applet with php? You could then pass the IP of the server as a parameter to the applet.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of php, how different is that from html?

Comment: PHP is completely separate from HTML but they are often used in conjunction with one another. You would need only very minimal usage to do what you are asking. You could start at w3schools web site here http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp  . The issue is that you are not using just one server which is strange, if you give us a little more information maybe I can recommend a different solution, but I do not know enough about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Dylan well html is a markup language and PHP is a scripting language used to develop web applications so...... completely different. However,, it is extremely easy and fast to learn! It is also well worth the effort. Perl is probably a more profound solution as it has many more uses than just web development but is relatively more complex. PHP was designed to easily and effectively put largely used functions at a developer's fingertips.

Comment: what we are doing is we are embedding this webserver with the applet on a board this will then allow people with in the company to veiw the status of the device which is what the applet shows. the database is hosted on the chip with the webserver and therefore i need to get the ip address that the webserver is "serving" from to get access from the database so it will update when it changes. also, the ipaddress will differ depending on who is using the device.

Comment: p.s. This looks like it will work for what i need but, Is it possible to pass the html/php documents root to the applet? For example, to get to the site containing the applet i currently have to go to "http://192.168.1.123/index.html" how would I send just ethier "192.168.1.123" or "http://192.168.1.123" to the applet (keeping in mind that this must work on anybodies network)???

Comment: Well first of all, now the web page would be ip.ip.ip.ip/index.php and I already gave you a link in the answer that explains the <param> tag of applets. You would need to use echo and other php functions to output the param tags and the value of the IP of the server.

Comment: @thatidiotguy k, now i'm having trouble with the php code i'm using, could you tell me if this would be correct   ' <PARAM name="Message" value='<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url;?>'>  '          Also do you call echo from within <?php ?>   ???                P.S. I did change doc type

Comment: All php code goes between <?php ?> tags. In terms of it being "right", you can format that information however you want, but those look correct to me. You realize that the server will need to have php/apache installed correct?

Comment: Well how exactly were you planning on serving a web page without apache? What OS are you running on?

Comment: i'm on windows 7 and am using the lighttpd for windows, availible at http://en.wlmp-project.net/downloads.php

Comment: Well unfortunately I have never worked with that at all. You will have to see whether you can use it as a php interpreter.

Comment: the sever host did work, i just didn't have php running correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You can get this information from the HttpServletRequest class. There are several methods included  which may be useful. Refer to the following docs as a resource:

[Interface ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)

[Interface HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

It's also documented here:

[Getting the IP Address and Hostname of the Local Machine](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html)

Comment: Off the top of my head, you would want to set it as a parameter on the launch page: Defining and Using Applet Parameters http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html